# Select Certificate to use for Azure VPN in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: vpn, azure, certificate, windows-10

I have two different Azure Accounts with VNet in it and a P2S VPN connection to the client. Each Client has two certificate install for each VPN and the two VPN configure on the computer, as the figure below describes.
[image]

In all of my Windows 7 Pro computer, I am able to select the certificate that I am going to use for the VPN that I am connecting at that moment, as the figure below shows.
[image]

Recently one of my computer upgrade to Widows 10 Pro and now I am not able to select the certificate that I want for the connection at that moment.
Error message: Not certificate found for VPN connection. Is there any way to have the Windows 7 Pro option to select the certificate back.

Comment: Do you mean you can't find where to select the certificate in windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

I think I understood your explanation, your client upgrade to windows 10 pro, and can't find where to select the certificate for VPN.

If I understand it correctly, we can select certificate from adapter settings -> network connections, like this:
[image]

Comment: Does this helpful? or what can I do for you?

Comment: Hi Jason. You understood well. It was really helpful. I am doing some testing now.

Comment: The type of connection is "WAN Miniport (SSTP)". In the first windows of your process, you have to force the connection in "Type if VPN" selecting "Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol (SSTP)". But after that, I get the Error message: "The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value.". But the single connection is fine with the VPN Client provided by Azure.

Comment: @FelixD. now, you are able to select the certificate:)  according to this error message, this issue may occur if the host name of the server that is specified in the VPN connection does not match the subject name that is specified on the SSL certificate that the server submits to the client computer. The SSL certificate Common Name (CN) must be the one which are using to connect to the VPN server using the windows VPN client.  More information please refer to this link. https://www.windowstechupdates.com/certificates-cn-name-not-match-passed-value/

Comment: @FelixD. Does it work now?

Comment: Ye. That link is for a VPN server on a Windows Server VM in Azure. I am serving my VPN directly from Azure Internet Gateway. I don't think so that I can apply that solution. Please, correct me.

Comment: @FelixD. Yes, the link talk about VPN server. I mean the error message talk about we use wrong certificate. Please re-install the certificate on your windows 10, and try again. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#a-nameinstallclientcerta10---install-the-client-certificate